# Use its functions in the repository (Doctrine + Zend Expressive)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, mezzio

Welcome. It is impossible to call its functions from the repository in an Action (Expressive Zend + Doctrine)

```
___________________

// App\Entity\Category
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id", columns={"id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{//}
___________________

// App\Repository\CategoryRepository
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function finderMethod($arguments){
        // Какие-либо действия
        return $arguments;
    }
}
___________________

// App\Action\PageAction
$category = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Category')-> ???
```

findAll(), findBy working as intended, what am I doing wrong? (*as far as I remember, in zf2 I had the same problem*)

Comment: What Errors are you getting? ***Are you sure $this->em is an instance of Entity Manager?*** Although this is not necessary; try adding a back-slash before App like so: **$this->em->getRepository('\App\Entity\Category')->???**

Comment: it worked, thank you

Comment: OK... Please, endorse the answer below as the Correct one so that Future visitors with a similar problem might benefit from it? Thanks... Cheers....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a repository you can use the fully qualified class name:

```
<?php 

$categoryRepository = $this->em->getRepository(App\Entity\Category::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

What Errors are you getting? Are you sure $this->em is an instance of Entity Manager? Although this is not necessary; try adding a back-slash before App like so:

```
<?php 
     $this->em->getRepository('\App\Entity\Category')->???
```